# How to bind to autocomplete selecteditem with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm currently implementing autocomplete box from syncfusion. The current selection mode is set to `Token`

```
<autocomplete:SfAutoComplete x:Name="autoComplete"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Location"
                                MultiSelectMode="Token"
                                HeightRequest="120"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                TokensWrapMode="Wrap" 
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}"
                                DataSource="{Binding FilteredLocations}"                                                   
                                Text="{Binding SearchLocation, Mode=TwoWay}" >
</autocomplete:SfAutoComplete>
```

I'm currently using MVVM approach, how do I bind to SelectedLocation without using object base type.

```
private ObservableCollection<SearchItem> _filteredLocations;
public ObservableCollection<SearchItem> FilteredLocations
{
    get { return _filteredLocations; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _filteredLocations, value); }
}
```

What I have that current works

```
public object SelectedLocation
{
    get { return _selectedLocation; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedLocation, value);
    }
}
```

But I don't want the type to be object, and what I change it to be `ObservableCollection<SearchItem>`, SelectedLocation is no longer picked up. May I get tips or suggestions to properly bind to the selecteditem when it's a collection.

What I tried that didn't work

```
public ObservableCollection<SearchItem> SelectedLocation
{
    get { return _selectedLocation; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedLocation, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited after the clarification from OP:**

It looks like you'll have to make it work by using `ObservableCollection<object>`. If you then want to access the individual SearchItem objects, you'll need a mechanism to call another method or property setter and cast the items there.

```
public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedLocation
{
    get { return _selectedLocation; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedLocation, value);
    }
}
```

For a full example of how to use the `ObservableCollection<object>` and then casting the results to strings (or in your case to `SearchItem`), take a look at this KB article: [How to get SelectedText from AutoComplete](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9291/how-to-get-selectedtext-from-autocomplete). It's not 1:1 to your use-case but should be enough to proceed.

Comment: Sorry maybe I phrased it poorly, I'm trying to bind to ObservableCollection<T>, not a single selected item.

Comment: Ah right, I missed the Tokens part. Let me have another look.

Comment: Edited the post @Phoenix

Comment: Thanks, that works. very odd that I have to cast but that'll do. Thank you