# How to prepopulate Autocomplete SelectedItem

Tags: xaml, xamarin, syncfusion

From my previous post, it helped be to determine how to bind to selecteditems, [How to bind to autocomplete selecteditem with ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677654/how-to-bind-to-autocomplete-selecteditem-with-observablecollection) But now I'm trying to enhance that logic.

I'm trying to have items preselected when my View is initialized. I've tried multiple options, but I can't seem to get items preselected. May I get some assistance. My current code below

Keyword Class

```
public class Keyword : ObservableObject
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _value, value); }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<object> _selectedKeywords = new ObservableCollection<object>();
private ObservableCollection<Keyword> _keywords = new ObservableCollection<Keyword>();


public TestViewModel()
{
    Keywords = new ObservableCollection<Keyword>() 
    { 
        new Keyword { Value = "Apples" }, 
        new Keyword { Value = "Bananas" }, 
        new Keyword { Value = "Celery" } 
    };
    SelectedKeywords = new ObservableCollection<object>(Keywords.Where(x => x.Value == "Apples"));
}

public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedKeywords
{
    get { return _selectedKeywords; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedKeywords, value); }
}
public ObservableCollection<Keyword> Keywords
{
    get { return _keywords; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _keywords, value); }
}
```

View

```
<autocomplete:SfAutoComplete MultiSelectMode="Token"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                                                
                            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            TokensWrapMode="Wrap" 
                            Text="{Binding Keyword, Mode=TwoWay }"
                            IsSelectedItemsVisibleInDropDown="false"
                            Watermark="Add..."
                            HeightRequest="120"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKeywords}"
                            DataSource="{Binding Keywords}">
</autocomplete:SfAutoComplete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have prepared sample from your code snippet and you have missed to add **DisplayMemberPath** property in the code snippet. Please find the sample from below location.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/AutoCompleteSample-270923957.zip

**Note**: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,

Dhanasekar

Comment: thanks a ton! Just a couple questions on the side side. Are there ways to add items to autocomplete box at run time on a click event? I can't seem to get two way binding to work perfectly. And also for the selectedItem, is there anyway to bind to ObservableCollection<T> instead of ObservableCollection<object> ?

Answer (score 1):

To make it preselected in your View Model set a value to the binding that you have binded on your View basically assign a value to `SelectedKeywords`

Something like:

```
SelectedKeywords = Keywords.FirstOrDefault();
```

You might need two-way binding not sure cause never used this control:

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKeywords, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: That won't quite work, I'm binding to ObservableCollection<T> not T itself.

Comment: Well i was about to ask you that why is it a observable collection there can be just one selected item you know that right?I mean unless there is a specific reason for having a collection of them

Comment: Well if you clicked on the link I provided, it gives a bit of information about the control. SelectedItem can be bound to an ObservableCollection<T> Or T. Not limited to one selected item. And setting Mode=TwoWay didn't solve it either.

Comment: That is what i am saying that you do not need the observable collection of objects there object is the base class of everything in C#, i mean object on its own is more than enough to handle collections

Comment: Your SelectedItem property binded to the ViewModel should be of the Type that is assigned to the DataSource in your ViewModel binding